# How to delete data using http.delete Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm Learning CRUD( Create,Read,Update,Delete) using rest api , I'm already GET & POST data, How to implement "http.delete()" in Flutter ?

I'm already Using this function, i can get ID for deleting data, but not deleting.

```
Future deleteMahasiswa(Map<String, dynamic> id) async {
    final response =
        await http.delete('${Urls.BASE_API_URL}/mahasiswa/delete?id=$id');
    return response.statusCode == 200;
  }

class Urls {
  static const BASE_API_URL = 'http://192.168.43.159/wpu-rest-server/apii/';
  static const BASE_HOST ='http://192.168.43.159/';
}
```

And This for View

```
void _deleteAction() async {
     final post = {
      "id": widget.id
    };
    bool result = await api.deleteMahasiswa(post);
    if (result) {
      _showSnackBar(context, 'Hapus ${widget.nama} Berhasil');
      debugPrint(widget.id);
    }
    else{
      _showSnackBar(context, 'Fail');
      debugPrint(widget.id);

      return null;

    }
    _refreshList();
  }
```

this for button onpressed

```
onPressed: () {
_deleteAction();
},
```

I'm mistake something ?

**Update**
I'm Try change my code like this :

```
Future deletedDeleted(String id) async {
    final _authority = "${Urls.BASE_API_HOST}";
    final _path = "/wpu-rest-server/apii/mahasiswa/delete/$id";
    // final _params = { "id" : id };
    final httpClient = HttpClient();
    final _uri = Uri.http(_authority, _path);
    final request = await httpClient.deleteUrl(_uri);
    request.headers.set('content-type', 'application/json');
    final response = await request.close();
    final responseBody = await response.transform(utf8.decoder).join();
    debugPrint(responseBody.toString());
    debugPrint(_uri.toString());
    return responseBody;
  }
```

My Console show me correct URL , but have message ID Null.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vbmvc.png)

Answer (score 0):

Use this method to delete

```
 Future<Map<String, dynamic>> commonDel(String url, Map jsonMap) async{
     HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
     HttpClientRequest request = await httpClient.deleteUrl(Uri.parse(url));
     request.headers.set('content-type', 'application/json');
     request.add(utf8.encode(json.encode(jsonMap)));
     HttpClientResponse response = await request.close();
     String reply = await response.transform(utf8.decoder).join();
     print(reply);
     httpClient.close();
     Map<String, dynamic>map = json.decode(reply);
     return map;
}
```

Comment: how to implement this code in view and button onpress ?

Comment: create your button then onPress or onTap : () => mydeletefuntion(url, map); https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/widgets/material#Buttons

Comment: Check out https://github.com/Ephenodrom/Dart-Basic-Utils for a HttpUtils class which helps you with http requests !

Comment: @Ephenodrom How to use the method Package ? I'm Using this method but get error : 

Future<Map<String, dynamic>> deleteForJson(String url,{Map<String, String> queryParameters, Map<String, String> headers}) async {
    final dataAsJson = await HttpUtils.deleteForJson('${Urls.BASE_API_URL}',queryParameters: queryParameters,headers: headers);
    var responseJson = json.decode(dataAsJson);
    print(dataAsJson);
    return dataAsJson;
  }

Comment: @ZeffryReynando please check my answer at github!