# Why I cannot do delete function?

Tags: php, flutter

I want to know why I can't delete my item? Is there any error in coding?

this is my view list that contain delete button function:

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:myapp/model/api.dart';
import 'package:myapp/model/attractionModel.dart';
import 'package:myapp/view/editAttraction.dart';
import 'package:myapp/view/addAttraction.dart';


class AdminViewList extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AdminViewListState createState() => _AdminViewListState();
}

class _AdminViewListState extends State<AdminViewList> {
  var loading = false;

  final list = new List<AttractionModel>();
  final GlobalKey<RefreshIndicatorState> _refresh = GlobalKey<RefreshIndicatorState>();
  Future<void> _viewData() async{
    list.clear();
    setState(() {
      loading = true;
    });
    final response = await http.get(BaseUrl.viewAttraction);
    if (response.contentLength == 2) {
      
    } else {
      final data = jsonDecode(response.body);
      data.forEach((api){
        final ab = new AttractionModel(
          api['id'], 
          api['attractionName'], 
          api['description'], 
          api['price'], 
          api['createdData'], 
          api['idUsers'], 
          api['name'],
          api['image'],

          );
          list.add(ab);
      });
      if (!mounted) return;
      setState(() {
        loading = false;
      });
    }
  }

  dialogDelete(String id){
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context){
        return Dialog(
          child: ListView(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
            shrinkWrap: true,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text("Are you sure want to delete this product?",
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 10.0,
              ),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                children: <Widget>[
                  InkWell(
                    onTap: (){
                      Navigator.pop(context);
                    },
                    child: Text("No")),
                  SizedBox(width: 20.0,),
                  InkWell(
                    onTap: (){
                      _delete(id);
                    },
                  child: Text("Yes")),
                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
        );
      }
    );
  }
  _delete(String id) async {
    final response = await http.post (BaseUrl.deleteAttraction, body: {
      "idAttraction" : id
    });
    final data = jsonDecode(response.body);
    int value = data['value'];
    String message = data ['message'];
    if (value == 1) {
      setState(() {
        Navigator.pop(context);
        _viewData();
      });
    } else {
      print(message);
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    _viewData();

  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(onPressed: (){
        Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute (builder: (context) => AddAttraction(_viewData)));
      },
      child: Icon(Icons.add),
    ),
    body: loading ? 
    Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()) : 
    RefreshIndicator(
      onRefresh: _viewData,
      key: _refresh,
          child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: list.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, i){
            final x = list[i];
            return Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
              child: Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Image.network('http://192.168.42.48/myapp/upload/'+ x.image,
                   width: 100.0,
                   height: 180.0,
                   fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 10.0,
                    ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text(x.attractionName, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
                        Text(x.description),
                        Text(x.price),
                        Text(x.name),
                        Text(x.createdData),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  IconButton(
                    onPressed: (){
                      Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => EditAttraction(x, _viewData)
                        ));
                    },
                    icon: Icon(Icons.edit),
                  ),
                  IconButton(
                    onPressed: (){
                      dialogDelete(x.id);
                    },
                    icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
    ),
    );
  }
}
```

and this is my delete.php file

```
<?php

    require  "../config/connect.php";

    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=="POST")
    {
        #code...
        $response = array();
       
        $idAttraction = $_POST['idAttraction'];
        
        $insert = "DELETE FROM attraction WHERE id = '$idAttraction' ";
        if (mysqli_query($con, $insert)) 
        {
            # code...
            $response['value']=1;
            $response['message']="deleted!";
            echo json_encode($response);
        } 
        else 
        {
            # code...
            $response['value']=0;
            $response['message']="Failed to delete";
            echo json_encode($response);
        }
    }
?>
```

can anyone help me to find out why I cannot delete my item? I am afraid that I forgot to put something or not declare something or maybe my coding is wrong. Thank you.

**EDITED**

I try to login and add new item. If I still in the login session, I can delete the new item that i already added. But, if I login and add new item, and then I logout, and when I login back, I can't delete the item that i added previously. This is my real problem.

Comment: Use http.delete instead of http.post

Comment: try out this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57394495/how-to-delete-data-using-http-delete-flutter

Answer (score 1):

Most probably, the problem is in your "*_delete*" function.

```
_delete(String id) async {
    final response = await http.post (BaseUrl.deleteAttraction, body: {
      "idAttraction" : id // this is the problem.
    });
    final data = jsonDecode(response.body);
    int value = data['value'];
    String message = data ['message'];
    if (value == 1) {
      setState(() {
        Navigator.pop(context);
        _viewData();
      });
    } else {
      print(message);
    }
  }
```

http.post expects key and value both in double-quotes ("") or single quotes ('').

replace your _delete function with the one below:

```
_delete(String id) async {
    final response = await http.post (BaseUrl.deleteAttraction, body: {
      "idAttraction" : "${id}"
    });
    final data = jsonDecode(response.body);
    int value = data['value'];
    String message = data ['message'];
    if (value == 1) {
      setState(() {
        Navigator.pop(context);
        _viewData();
      });
    } else {
      print(message);
    }
  }
```

Comment: already replaced it. but still the message "Failed to delete" appeared in the terminal..

Comment: I try to login and add new item. If I still in the login session, I can delete the new item that i already added. But, if I login and add new item, and then I logout, and when I login back, I can't delete the item that i added previously. This is my actual problem..hmm